# C++ Using classes in other classes failing

Tags: c++, class

I have a Display class that uses SDL to write pixels to the screen. I'd like another class (Triangle) to be able to use this already existent class object, so I've been trying to pass the object by address.

It's sort of working, in the sense that it is actually calling the methods. However, I was getting a segmentation fault in the DrawPixel function. After checking gdb and checking what values are in the function, I figured out that the color_buffer array does not exist (note that when DrawPixel is called directly from the display class in main it works fine).

After a little more testing, I determined that window_width, window_height etc are not set in the Triangle's version of the Display object. But they do exist in the original Display object.

So I'm assuming that I am not properly passing in my object, but I'm uncertain how to fix this issue as I thought passing by address would work just fine. How can I pass an already existing/instantiated class to another class?

I've also tried putting color_buffer into public variables in case private was causing it, but that didn't help.

Example:

```
main.cpp

int main() {
    Display display;
    Triangle triangle(&display);

    // This doesn't work
    triangle.DrawTriangle(300, 500, 0xFFFFFF00);

    // This does work
    display.DrawPixel(300, 500, 0xFFFFFF00);
    return 0;
}
```

```
triangle.hpp

class Triangle {
    private:
        Display* display;
    public:
        DrawTriangle(int x, int y, uint32_t color);
};
```

```
triangle.cpp

Triangle::Triangle(Display* display) {
    display=display;
}

Triangle::DrawTriangle(int x, int y, uint32_t color) {
    display->DrawPixel(x, y, color);
}
```

```
display.hpp

class Display {
    private:
        // SDL Stuff defined here
        uint32_t* color_buffer;
        int window_width = 1920;
        int window_height = 1080;

    public:
        Display();
        DrawPixel(int x, int y, uint32_t color);
};
```

```
display.cpp

Display::Display() {
    // SDL Stuff declared
    color_buffer = new uint32_t[window_width * window_height];
}

Display::DrawPixel(int x, int y, uint32_t color) {
    // This is receiving the correct values, but doesn't allow me to access
    // any index of color_buffer.
    color_buffer[(y * window_width) + x] = color;
}
```

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<uint32_t>` and passing a `Display&` instead of a `Display*`. But how does that compile? `DrawPixel` has no return type (and should be named `drawPixel` - lowercase).

Comment: `display.DrawPixel` won't compile, please show a [mre]

Comment: Sorry I retyped a lot of the code for SO. Anyways, the issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Triangle::Triangle(Display* display) {
    display=display;
}
```

the `display` is not the member of your class.Use `this->display = display` instead

Comment: That's one reason you should name your members somehing like `m_display` or `display_`

Comment: Using initialiser lists would be better than using `this`

Comment: Thank you, that makes complete sense and worked. I completely forgot about this since I've been working in C lately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "this" in Triangle constructor. That should solve the problem.

```
Triangle(Display* display) {
            this->display=display;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to add to the answers above:

- use a different naming convention for member variables - this way it is very easy to avoid typos. `_display, m_display, Display_` (Clang style =) )
- class members are private by default so if you are following convention where attributes are defined on top, there's no need to add `private:`
- Some prefer references (e.g. `Display&`), mostly to save typing `->`, since if `Display goes out of scope it will have the same hilarious effect as passing a pointer.
- static analyzers look down on pointer arithmetic(due to possible out-of-bounds writes).

You can use std::array from  header:

```
  static constexpr int WIDTH = 1920;
  static constexpr int HEIGHT = 1080;
  std::array<uint32_t, WIDTH* HEIGHT> m_color_buffer{};
```

and then either use `m_color_buffer[index] = color` (no bounds checking, random memory gets written if you write out of bounds in release and normally an exception in debug), or use `m_color_buffer.at(index)` - slower but this way you get an exception in release mode, but the compiler may complain about the stack size, as the definition is essentially the same as `uint32_t buffer[WIDTH*HEIGHT]`. `std::vector` is a better alternative - it hides buffer allocation, manages memory (no need to delete) at expense of the 2 extra pointers for begin and the end of the vector.

- The code example lacked a destructor. Every `new` should have an accompanying `delete` hence either add it or just switch to a standard library container to avoid the headache =)
- Last but not least - both classes override constructors. `Display` also manages resources. What happens when you copy `Display` instances? Move them? It is a bit of a headache and leads to a bit of a boilerplate, but it is best to implement [Rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) members and avoid accidental surprises =)

PS. C++ is a beautiful language =)

Comment: Thank you I definitely will be using your advice. I am just learning C++ so it's all a bit overwhelming despite having experience with Python, C and Java.